# Open view SQL by view name in stored procedure (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic, plsql, view

I like to do query by opening a view in stored procedure. My requirements are

1. view name is dynamic (parameter to stored procedure)
2. using text column in all_views table as SQL and execute immediate it
   (not sure it is good idea to do query with this)

I was stopped how to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE INTO var` where I want to dump all rows in that variable 'var'. The stored procedure code is as per below. I put data type UNKNOWN to variable I declare in procedure because different view return different rowtype.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Send_Report(p_vname VARCHAR2)IS 
       rfound NUMBER;
       vrpt_qry all_views.text%TYPE;
       v_file  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
       v_rset UNKNOWN;
BEGIN

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT text FROM all_views WHERE UPPER(view_name) = :p1' INTO vrpt_qry USING UPPER(p_vname);
       v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR(
              location => 'oradir',
              filename => 'fname.txt',
              open_mode => 'w',
              max_linesize => 32767                  
       );

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE vrpt_qry INTO v_rset;
       FOR indx IN 1..v_rset.COUNT LOOP                      
           UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, v_rset);
       END LOOP;
       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
    END IF;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
         RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: You would have to parse the query in detail using `dbms_sql`, which is a bit of an exercise. If the aim is to generate a CSV file you might have a look at http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL to get the text of the view from `all_views`. However, I don't think you need to anyway (and it might not work if the view is in a different schema). Your dynamic query can just be `'select * from someview'`, although you might need a `where` clause. Also the exception handler isn't adding any value, as the default behavior for an unhandled exception is to fail the call and print the error stack anyway, with the advantage that the default handling retains the original line number and doesn't duplicate `sqlcode` ;)